# Why isn't my jQuery selector working?

Tags: jquery, css, selector

I'm writing a simple script that replaces two images. The first one swaps in fine, but the second one for some reason will not fire. It's got to be something simple that I'm missing. Maybe the 'div.singleTint img' selector? Can someone take a look and double check my work?

Here's my HTML:

```
    <div id="beerGlassOverlay">
    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/beerOverlay.png" class="glassreplace">
</div>

<li class="image-rollover">
    <a href="http://brasco.co/Mims/meet-the-breweries/miller-beers/" target="_blank">
        <img width="177" height="186" src="http://brasco.co/Mims/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/miller1.png" class="attachment-full wp-post-image" alt="miller" title="miller" />
    </a>
    <div class="singleTint">
        <img width="279" height="524" src="http://brasco.co/Mims/wp-content/uploads/shrekBeer.png" class="attachment-full" alt="shrekBeer" title="shrekBeer" />  
    </div><!-- End singleTint-->
</li>
```

Here's my jQuery:

```
$('li.image-rollover').mouseover(function() {   
$('img.glassreplace').attr({//Change the src and size info on hover         
    src: ('div.singleTint img', this).src,
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%'
    });
});`
```

Comment: You missed the `$` at the `src: ('div...`-part. should be `$('div.singleTint img')`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

change this:

```
src: ('div.singleTint img', this).src,
```

to:

```
src: $('div.singleTint img', this).attr('src'),
```

Answer (score 0):

`src: ('div.singleTint img', this).src,` should become `src: $('div.singleTint > img', this).attr("src"),`

(I've added child selector - `>`)

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing the jQuery object reference on the third line of your code (the $)?

```
 $('li.image-rollover').mouseover(function() {   
 $('img.glassreplace').attr({//Change the src and size info on hover         
    src: $('div.singleTint img', this).src, //Added the jQuery object in front of the parenthesis.
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%'
    });
 });
```